# Asus K75VM laptop fans not detected, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laptop, asus, overheating, fan, detect

My laptop fans seem to be completely overlooked by Ubuntu, so my CPU temp gets over 50*c despite low CPU usage. (Inbefore: proprietary GPU drivers are installed, which fixed the initial problem with high CPU usage.)

Still on Ubuntu 14.04, I tried to follow the steps here:
https://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/
I was also advised to install laptop-mode-tools OR TLP (tried them one after another) but all those things seem to boil down to pwmconfig always responding:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

The laptop is a multiboot with Win 7 and is used as DTR = I don't quite need advanced energy fine-tuning.

What do I do to make the fan(s) visible to Ubuntu at all?
Please keep in mind that I am a complete beginner. Here is my `dmidecode` output, if it can be of any help: http://pastebin.com/uLY6Px0R . Thank you!

Comment: Did check for drivers in "Additional Drivers"?

Comment: Yes, thanks, [this is all I got from there](http://s5.postimg.org/erttn35h3/Oprogramowanie_i_aktualizacje_004.png): the GPU, and a CPU driver which assigned itself to an "Unknown device". Nothing found related to cooling/fans.
I noticed the temps jump especially bad after I launch Firefox o.O Even though CPU usage drops back to the normal low after that...
[pic] (http://s5.postimg.org/rupg6cvp3/Psensor_Temperature_Monitor_006.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have an `Asus K75VM` laptop which has an `Intel H76 chipset`. The mobile version of this chipset has no fan control outputs so you do not have the necessary hardware for software fan control under any operating system.

Your fan speed is controlled by your BIOS. It sounds like it is working as intended as 50 degrees Celsius is a normal temperature for a laptop CPU. If you want to tune the fan or power management setings you can probably find these under the `advanced settings`page of your BIOS.

`laptop-mode tools` and `tlp` do much more than attempt to control the fan speeds. Install one or the other but not both.

Comment: Excuse me the degree of questionning but what did you mean by `advanced settings`? Ubuntu packages with that name point me to CompizConfig or [this weird thing] (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-tweak-tool/). And I never had to tweak BIOS itself because of Windows before.

Comment: @Karola It is a page in your BIOS.